# Can not installing Joomla 3.1.5

Tags: joomla, content-management-system, joomla2.5, joomla3.0

I bought domain and hosting, and then I copy joomla 3.1.5 files to hosting with ftp. After I try to installing joomla with type "www.myWebSiteDomain.com/joomla3.1.5" an unstructured and relatively ugly installer page was shown. after  I filling the fields, I click on "Next", but nothing was happen. now I can not install joomla 3.1.5. please help me to installing it to run my web site.
Thanks

Comment: can you please provide a screenshot of what you're seeing?

Comment: Did you purchase hosting and domain at the same time? If not did you map the domain to the new host? and/or map within the hosting account?

Comment: What hosting company are you using? When it comes to hosting, you should use a host that is configured to run Joomla. Rochen and Cloud Access are both good.